# How to use Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to Encode my MVC Model with the following code but the alert message gives me a null value. I'm not sure why it's giving me a null value because this is a create form. I'm trying to create a model from this and my html Code has the following look:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                var JsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))';

                alert(JsonModel); // json as string

                var model = JSON.parse(JsonModel); // will give json
                alert(model);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Home/Index",
                    data: {"cus" :  model},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("done");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Error!!!!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This process is a pain in the ass and can be easily avoided using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267942/submitting-partial-view-data-from-parent-view/27292486#27292486) which will encode your form in a way that MVC understands, so it can implicitly convert back to your model type.

Comment: thanks !!! i'll have a look.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267942/submitting-partial-view-data-from-parent-view/27292486#27292486) shows (in the JQuery section) how you can get around using `Json.Encode` altogether.

The basic idea behind it is that by using a jQuery function you can build a JSON object, one that MVC will be able to parse into a data model, out of any form.

The function is as follows:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

In your case, your AJAX would become

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../Home/Index",
     data: { cus : JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()) },
     success: function(data){
         alert("done");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error!!!!");
     }
 });
```

If you have trouble getting `$('form')` working, possibly if you have numerous forms on the same page, use classes or IDs to uniquely identify your forms.

Answer (score 8):

It's returning null because it *is* null. The data that the user will eventually enter into the form is not available at the time the page is rendering (and your call to `Json.Encode(Model)` runs). Things like JavaScript run *client-side*, while all the Razor stuff runs *server-side* before it's sent down to the client. If you want to get the user-entered data from the form for use in your AJAX call, then you need to do as @Sippy suggests and retrieve it via JavaScript:

```
$('form').serializeObject();
```

Also, in case you do need to actually encode the model when rendering (for maybe use with something like Knockout), you don't need to set it as a string and then parse the string. Just set it as a regular JavaScript object. That's all JSON is anyways:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: While unintuitive, using JSON.parse will be faster here. For example, `var obj= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');` Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0

Comment: @Onosa thanks for your comment - that was a worthy, eyes opening 6mins video...

Answer (score 0):

This sample, encode a model (that is a `List<My>`) and POST it to an action as a Json object named model.

```
var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
    var id = rowid;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'DeleteRows',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: '{ "model": { "rows":' + jsonModel + '}}'
    })
    .success(function (result) { $("#grdRows").empty(); $("#grdRows").html(result); })
    .error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status + ' - ' + ajaxOptions + ' - ' + thrownError); alert(xhr.responseText); });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to pass a model to an action method (HttpGet)
with an Url.Action Helper

```
  @model AddViewModel

   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            openDoc();
        });

        function openDoc() {

            var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';
            var obj = JSON.parse(model);
            var params = $.param(obj);
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetPdf", "Declaration")?' + params;

            window.open(url);
        }

    </script>
```