# Getting errors converting a C# List to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

I'm passing a `List<Results>` object to my view as the model.
On that page I'm trying to convert it to Javascript to use client side.

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
var data = JSON.parse(model);
self.Results = ko.observableArray(data);
```

When I do I get this error
`jQuery.Deferred exception: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 240 of the JSON data`

I know I need to escape the data but not sure at what point or how.

Comment: can you post value of  [var model]  and Results class structure

Comment: You might have any escape character in your data. Try to unescape it before parsing into json.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701542/4065876.

Comment: @Z.R.T. I can see it's encoding single quotes but it's not handling double slashes \\

Comment: @user3953989  i think, you need to escape double slashes when you build Model object, for example : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { aa = @"\\"}))